# Constant javascript listener for media query?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the innerhtml of an element when page size is decreased, such as a media query in css. How can I make this function constantly listen to the watchmedia query so that it adjusts? This solution will only work if the page size is 37.5em when the page is loaded. I figure I could use a setTimeout function and a callback to run every couple of seconds, but that would cause performance issues

```
let min = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 37.5em)");


if (min.matches) {
  document.querySelector(".header__resume").innerHTML = "Resume" + "&rarr;";
}
```

Comment: Add a listener for the `resize` event.

Comment: there are observers which can do for you, there are better for listening for `resize` event

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner el atributo "data-label" en la etiqueta que quieres cambiar y cuando la ventana alcance el tamaño que quieres, en el css usar la propiedad content => content: attr(data-label).
Haciendo esto el innerHTML cambiaría su contenido cuando paso al tamaño marcado en la media query

```
HTML: 
<tag data-label="media query content">Current content</tag>

CSS:
@media all and (max-width: 37.5em) {
  tag { content: attr(data-label) }
}
```